# NSPredicate Query for Subsets and "Close Enough" Subsets

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

Bit new to `NSPredicates` and Core Data in general, so trying to grasp my head around need to do the following:

I have two Entities that have a Many-to-many relationship:

`MyContainerEntity` contains a many to many relationship with `MyObjectEntity`.

Say the list of `MyObjectEntity` is: A, B, C, D, E, F

And `MyContainerEntity` is made up of:

```
Container1 - A, B, C
Container2 - B, C, D
Container3 - A, B, D
Container4 - A, D, F
```

That is, Container1 contains a relationship with `MyObjectEntity` A, B and C and so on.

I would like to make a query where I send in a list of `MyObjectEntity` and all `MyContainerEntity` objects that are a subset of that list are returned.

For example:

(A,B,D,F) would return Container3, and Container4.

Then the follow up would be getting something that is "close" with some error value. Say only 1 object missing. For example:

(A, B) would return Container1 and Container3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first part of your problem, have you tried defining a predicate such as:

```
ALL objects IN $OBJECTS_PARAM
```

where OBJECTS_PARAM value would be an array or set that you pass into to the evaluation via a "predicateWithSubstitutionVariables" argument?

For the follow up question, I'm not sure if it is possible directly in a predicate. It seems like it might be better to implement such a query manually in code rather than relying on an NSPredicate to do that.